# Blackwell's informativeness criterion

Tags: probability-theory, convex-analysis, information-theory

Let $a=(a_1,\dots,a_i,\dots,a_n)$ be a probability vector, i.e. $\forall i: a_i\ge0$ and $\sum_i a_i=1$. 
Suppose $b$ is another $n$-dimensional probability vector.

Is it true that there always exists an $n\times n$ matrix $M$ with non-negative entries and whose columns sum to $1$ such that $b=M^Ta$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your $a$ is a row vector, you want to write that as $b =  a M^T$.
Then simply take $M$ as the matrix whose columns are all equal to $b^T$.